# Problema en la llamada al botón con listener

Tags: javascript

estoy aprendiendo JS y no encuentro la solución a este problema:

Tengo un `listener` en este desplegable para saber que opción coge, pero también tengo este botón que cuando entra este `if` el `listener` del botón no funciona, supongo que será porque está dentro de un `listener`, a ver si podéis echar una mano, gracias.

```
var numeroParticipantes = document.getElementById("numero-participantes");
numeroParticipantes.addEventListener("input", function () {
  var selectedOption = this.options[numeroParticipantes.selectedIndex];
  console.log(selectedOption.value + ": " + selectedOption.text);

  if (selectedOption.value == "2") {
    console.log("Ha entrado en if 1");
    imgCoches[0].src = "img/car1.png";
    imgCoches[1].src = "img/car2.png";
    imgCoches[0].width = "200";
    imgCoches[1].width = "200";
}
});

(document).ready(function () {
  $("#empezar").on("click", function () {
 $("#c1").animate(
      {
        left: "1200px",
        
      },
      a, 
      "linear",
      function () {
      //  alert("Ganó el primero")
       // $(this).after("<div>Llego el primero</div>");
      }
    );
    

  });


});


Añado el código html!!

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Carreras de coches!!</h2>

<label for="Número participantes">Número participantes</label>
 <select name="participantes" id="numero-participantes">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione Participantes</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" >2</option>
  <option value="3" >3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>

<div id="imagenes">
  <!-- <img class="seleccionado" src="img/car1.png" />
  <img class="noSeleccionado" src="img/car2.png" />
  <img class="noSeleccionado" src="img/car3.png" /> -->
  <img class="imagen1" src="" id="c1" /> 
  <img class="imagen2" src="" id="c2" />
  <img class="imagen3" src="" id="c3" />
  <img class="imagen4" src="" id="c4" />
  <img class="imagen5" src="" id="c5" />
  <img class="imagen6" src="" id="c6" />
  <img class="imagen7" src="" id="c7" />
  <img class="imagen8" src="" id="c8" />
  <img class="imagen9" src="" id="c9" /> 
</div>

<input type="button" id="empezar" value="Comenzar" />
<input type="button" id="reiniciar" value="Reiniciar" />

<script src="js/script.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Añado el código html!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Carreras de coches!!</h2>

<label for="Número participantes">Número participantes</label>
 <select name="participantes" id="numero-participantes">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccione Participantes</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" >2</option>
  <option value="3" >3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>

<div id="imagenes">
  <!-- <img class="seleccionado" src="img/car1.png" />
  <img class="noSeleccionado" src="img/car2.png" />
  <img class="noSeleccionado" src="img/car3.png" /> -->
  <img class="imagen1" src="" id="c1" /> 
  <img class="imagen2" src="" id="c2" />
  <img class="imagen3" src="" id="c3" />
  <img class="imagen4" src="" id="c4" />
  <img class="imagen5" src="" id="c5" />
  <img class="imagen6" src="" id="c6" />
  <img class="imagen7" src="" id="c7" />
  <img class="imagen8" src="" id="c8" />
  <img class="imagen9" src="" id="c9" /> 
</div>

<input type="button" id="empezar" value="Comenzar" />
<input type="button" id="reiniciar" value="Reiniciar" />

<script src="js/script.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Agrega el html a la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Intenta dandole relativo a las imagenes

```
<style>
  #imagenes img {
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    margin: 2px 0px;
    display: block;
  }
</style>
```

---

Comment: Vale, gracias! Me funcionaba, pero el problema es que una vez que entra en el if que recoge la imagen, le doy click al botón empezar que sería el de acelerar, no me funciona! y no entiendo porque, sime podeis ayudar, Gracias!!

Comment: por lo que se puede ver en el código que pusiste, el problema no está ahí, debe estar en algún otro lado que falta que nos muestres